# Error loading DLL from Spyder but not from Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, spyder, dllimport

I'm trying to load a dll in my python code. This dll allows the control of a scientific camera and was developed by the manufacturer. The dlls provided by the company are placed in the same folder of the script. Unfortunately I'm really not an expert of dll, but it seems it has dependecies (I checked using 'Dependecies Walker').

The loading of this library (`ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(...)`) has always been successful until I tried to add its directory to the `PATH` (`sys.path.insert(0, ...)`). From that moment on, even deleting added directories, I always get this error:

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

I tested the exact same script on another PC (synced through Google Drive) and it worked perfectly. Assuming it was a problem of my Spyder settings, I uninstalled Anaconda and Spyder, then I installed them again. The error was still present.

The only way I found to be working is to launch **Spyder from Anaconda Navigator** and run the exact same code.

Since I was worried the problem was in the `PATH`, I checked the paths `sys.path` for these 3 tests, and the list of directories was exactly the same.

Can somebody smarter than me tell me why this is happening and how I can solve it?
(Python 3.7.7 - Spyder 4.1.2 - IPython 7.13.0 - Windows 10)